# Toggle each panel in it's miniswitch

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Have a big switch that activates all the panels (convert to off (grey) to on (green). I want to do this on each miniswitch in the panel, so if i click in the miniswitch in the panel with the id 2, it's only convert to on the panel with id 2, not all the panels.

Main structure (example of 1 panel):

```
<div id="taskPanel" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div id="4" class="panel panel-off2">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="ptitle">Task 4</div>
          <div class="optiongroup">  
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit yellow"></span>
            <div class="miniswitch">
              <input type="checkbox" data-id="4">
              <label>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i>
              </label>
            </div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">  
        <div class="col-xs-12"><strong>Planning:</strong>&nbsp;0/10 * * * * ?</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <strong>URI:</strong>&nbsp;/cron/test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".switch").click(function () {
  $("#tp1")[0].innerHTML = ( $("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas" )? 'Desactivar todas' : 'Activar todas';
  var varVisible = ( $("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas" )? 'panel-off2' : 'panel-success';

  $('div.panel').each( function(){
    this.className = "panel " + varVisible;
  });

  var miniswitch = ( $("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas" )? false : true;

  $('.miniswitch').each( function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',miniswitch);
  });  

  /*
  if ($("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas") {
    $("#tp1").text("Desactivar todas");
  } else {
    $("#tp1").text("Activar todas");
  }
  */
});

$(".miniswitch").click(function () {
  $("#tp1")[0].innerHTML = ( $("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas" )? 'Desactivar todas' : 'Activar todas';
  var varVisible = ( $("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas" )? 'panel-off2' : 'panel-success';

  $('div.panel').each( function(){
    this.className = "panel " + varVisible;
  });

  var miniswitch = ( $("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas" )? false : true;

  $('.miniswitch').each( function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked',miniswitch);
  });

  /*
  if ($("#tp1").text() == "Activar todas") {
    $("#tp1").text("Desactivar todas");
  } else {
    $("#tp1").text("Activar todas");
  }
  */
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.switch-light').bootstrapSwitch();
  /*
  $('.switch-light input').on('change', function() {
    $('.panel').toggleClass("panel-off2", !this.checked).toggleClass("panel-success", this.checked);
  })
  */
});
```

This is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cL7U3/3/

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4tr4/1/ ?

Comment: Yes, but with this code... EDIT: I see that this work on my new code!! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think we should help with this completely broken code - we might get it to work (somehow) but it will still be a horrible mess. Brutal.

Comment: there are lot of problems in the code... if you can see what you really want to do we might be able to help more

Comment: or see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q4tr4/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/cL7U3/5/)

You were selecting all `div.panel` elements, you need to only select the parent one of the currently clicked switch:

```
$(this).parents('div.panel').each(function () {
    this.className = "panel " + varVisible;
});
```